# Angular ngrx design - add new item to the list and not reload the list from the backend

Tags: angular, user-interface, ngrx

I have a list of notes and a textbox/button to create a new note. When the page loads, I fetch the list of notes from the backend. When the user presses the button to create a new note, we post this new note to the backend. Question is about general UI design best practices.. is it okay to just add the new note to the store slice on the UI such that shows up in the list of notes.. or would it be better practice to now reload the notes list from the backend and have it update that way?

- Assume no push notifications in this application

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends, this isn't something we can't decide based on the information in this question.

If it's just one person using the app, it will be fine to just append the note.
If the application is used by many users and these users update notes, it might be a good idea to refresh the whole list. But also perhaps not.

You can also append the note to the list on the client side because this is fast, then wait for the backend to response with the new list to update the current state.